# Add List to List<List<>> collections in java

Tags: java, list, addition

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> tmp = new LinkedList<Integer>();
tmp.add(2);
list.add(tmp);
tmp.add(3);
list.add(tmp);
```

The result of list is `[[2,3],[2,3]];` I just confused about that why it is not `[[2],[2,3]]`. And when I use `list.add(new LinkedList<Integer>(tmp))` it will work. I print tmp, it is still `[2], [2,3]`, it is not changed. Why that happen?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because both two elements of list refer to the same object temp. If you want the result [[2],[2,3]], you can create new another tmp object.

Comment: In the current code, you have only instantiated `tmp` a single time, so it it is added to `list` twice, but it is the same object.

Answer (score 3):

You added a reference to `tmp` to `list`. When you added it, `tmp` only contained [2,3]. After the addition to `list`, you added 3 to the same reference of `tmp`. This caused both "copies" to have [2,3].

One way could be to create a new list and do the following

```
tmp = new LinkedList<Integer>();
tmp.add(3);
list.add(tmp);
```

Now, list will look like [[2],[3]].

If you want list to be [[2],[2,3]]...

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> tmp = new LinkedList<Integer>();
tmp.add(2);

// add a copy of this linkedlist to the "BIG" list
list.add(new LinkedList<Integer>(tmp));
tmp.add(3);
list.add(tmp);
```

let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses references to objects that you create with `new` to refer to those objects. In this example, the variable `tmp` is actually a reference to the `LinkedList` object on the heap.

Since `list` is a list of objects, it is actually a list of references to those objects. In this case, its two elements are references to the same heap object, `tmp`.